# Setting Standard Permissions on new Liferay JournalArticle

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Here´s my question: Is there a simple way to configure liferay so that newly created JournalArticles get a certain permission (like : "All new articles are not viewable by guests" or "All new articles are viewable by guests") ?

Thanks for your efforts !!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new journal article under **permissions** you will be seeing **view able by** option.
You can give permission there for **particular** article.

Is your expectation is to give permission one time **common** for **all articles**?So that whenever you create it will not be viewed by guest.

Can you please tell whether it will be viewed by guest in **future**.For ex:After some **approval** process through workflow.

Comment: Hi, my question was more like: "how do i make sure that i can publish a journal article without having to set the permissions each time myself?" Is there a way to configure that each new article gets guest/no guest permissions?